# React Native: PhoneAccount connection service requires BIND_TELECOM_CONNECTION_SERVICE permission

Tags: android, react-native

[image]

after installing `npm i react-native-callkeep`
im getting the below error:

> PhoneAccount connection service requires
> BIND_TELECOM_CONNECTION_SERVICE permission. Remote stack trace: at
> com.android.server.telecom.PhoneAccountRegi
> strar.registerPhoneAccount(PhoneAccountRegi strar.java:823) at
> com.android.server.telecom. TelecomServicelm
> pi$1.registerPhoneAccount(TelecomServicelm pl.java:576) at
> com.android.internal.telecom.ITelecomService $Stub.on Transact
> (ITelecom Service.java:958) at
> android.os.Binder.execTransactinternal(Binder.j ava:1190) at
> android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:115 9)

Answer (score 0):

I was same problem, so you need add this in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<service android:name="io.wazo.callkeep.VoiceConnectionService" android:label="Wazo" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_TELECOM_CONNECTION_SERVICE" android:foregroundServiceType="phoneCall" android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.telecom.ConnectionService"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name="io.wazo.callkeep.RNCallKeepBackgroundMessagingService"/>
```

This is my complete file, because you need add in correct order:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.developervini.gcondoapp">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_TELECOM_CONNECTION_SERVICE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.audio.output"/>
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone"/>
  <queries>
    <intent>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
      <data android:scheme="https"/>
    </intent>
  </queries>
  <application android:name=".MainApplication" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:allowBackup="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.ENABLED" android:value="true"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_SDK_VERSION" android:value="48.0.0"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATES_CHECK_ON_LAUNCH" android:value="ALWAYS"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATES_LAUNCH_WAIT_MS" android:value="0"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATE_URL" android:value="https://exp.host/@developervini/Gcondo"/>
    <service android:name="io.wazo.callkeep.VoiceConnectionService" android:label="Wazo" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_TELECOM_CONNECTION_SERVICE" android:foregroundServiceType="phoneCall" android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.telecom.ConnectionService"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name="io.wazo.callkeep.RNCallKeepBackgroundMessagingService"/>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" android:theme="@style/Theme.App.SplashScreen" android:exported="true" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="com.developervini.gcondoapp"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" android:exported="false"/>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).